# DNS conditional forwarders for zones on external trusted domain from untrusted domain

Tags: active-directory, internal-dns

I work for an international company and the factory I work for has it's own local domain which has an external trust with the company's main domain so those users can authenticate on our domain as well.
I've inherited the setup and would like to make some changes to the DNS forwarders.

Our local domain: our.domain.name.**company.com**
Company domain(s): name1.sub1.**company.com** (our trust is with this domain)
name1.sub2.**company.com**
whatever.sub3.**company.com**
**company.com** (used for intranet and public site's etc.)

As you can see all ending at the same **company.com**

We currently have the company DNS server set up as forwarders which works fine, but every query not for our local domain is being forwarded to their DNS servers (eg. google.com etc.).

[image: forwarders]

What we want is that all the queries towards our.domain.name.**company.com** are being handled by our own DNS servers, queries towards *.**company.com** (so this includes **company.com** and every sub.**company.com** EXCEPT our.domain.name.**company.com**) need to be forwarded to the company DNS servers and every other query (google.com, serverfault.com, etc...) should be send for example Google DNS servers.

What is the best way to achieve this?
Should we remove the company DNS servers as forwarders and put the Google DNS servers there, and then create **Conditional Forwarders** for **company.com**?
If so, will it be enough to just add one conditional forwarder for **company.com** or do we need to add a conditional forwarder for every (sub)domain we need to forward towards their DNS servers?
Or is it maybe as simple as creating a **Forward Lookup Zone** for **company.com** and add their servers as DNS servers (we do have a few _msdcs.sub1.**company.com**, name1.sub2.**company.com**, our.domain.name.**company.com**, sub1.**company.com**, our-external.**company.com** in here but this shouldn't conflict)?

Or am I completely overthinking this and is there a much simpler way to achieve this?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

**Edit:** Add the desired DNS flows

[image: DNS flows]

**Edit:** As per **strongline**'s answer:

[image]

Comment: Hello @GregAskew, thank you. But would a zone for company.com be enough to include all it's subdomains (and of course skip our own domain since we need those handled by our own DNS servers) or do I need to add a zone for each company.com, sub1.company.com, name1.sub1.company.com, etc.? I've edited the original question to include the desired DNS flows

Comment: @GregAskew Just to be a 100% sure that I understand what you mean: You're saying I should create a **Conditional Forwarder** for company.com only to also include all subdomains (and our own DNS servers should respond to queries towards our own domain by default of course, and forward all other (public website) queries towards for example Google DNS). Also did you review the DNS flow image I added?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Company head office should own and host zone company.com, beneath it, it also hosts sub1/2/3 sub-domains. Then on company DNS, it should delegate ourDomain.company.com to the DNS servers that you support. On your DNS servers, set up a conditional forwarder that points to company.com DNS servers (you might not need an explicit conditional forwarder for parent, it might be implicit, I don't quite remember. But an explicit forwarder is a sure way to do it). You don't need forwarders to sub1/2/3 - DNS server for the parent domain should handle the flow since it is authoritative for sub1/2/3.

In short, yourDomain.company.com is nothing more special than just another sub domain, which can be hosted on head office DNS, or delegate out to a separate DNS infrastructure (this is your case)

Comment: Thanks @strongline, exactly what I thought. I've edited my original question at the bottom as per your answer. This is what you mean right? Then remove all the forwarders from the DNS settings and just add Google (or whatever) DNS forwarders there.

Comment: correct. 1) in conditional forwarder, list yoru head office DNS servers for company.com; 2) if you want to use google DNS for internet domains, make it your default forwarder (on DNS server properties window)

Comment: Thank you very much for confirming @strongline, I will add this to our change and accept your answer!

Answer (score 0):

If you want your own DNS servers to handle any DNS queries for zones outside your corporate zones, (google.com etc) take out all the forwarders.

If your clients send your DNS server a query for one of your internal zones in company.com , your DNS server will naturally send the query onto the parent zones DNS servers to handle the query, you don't need to setup specific forwarders for those zones.

Id recommend you diagramming the setup out before you make any changes so you understand how your environment is working, if you inherited the environment, something may not be set up how you think.

Comment: Hello, thank you for the fast answer! Remove all the forwarders and put the Google DNS in there you mean I assume? Not sure about the internal zones though. How do our DNS servers know where to forward those queries to if the DNS servers are not defined?